# Xamarin Forms not Displaying new page when using <Editor> element and SDK

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

The project is done in Xamarin Forms but this is an iOS-specific problem because we do not use SDK on the Android project.

When trying to navigate from page to page neither on Simulator nor on real iPhone will Navigation.PushAsync(new TicketPage()); push to a new page while there is an  on the TicketPage (this is the 'next' page, but it does not work no matter what page it is if it has in it).

There is no Error when trying to PushAsync to the next page.
When a field is removed from .xaml file it works as intended but since I need a multiline input field this is becoming an issue.

There is an AppConnectSDKBinding (SDK for Integration with MobileIron service) and when SDK is present the application does not show pages with  in them.

Is there another Multi-line text input similar to that I can use because I have to have SDK in this project?

Edit:

When trying to run/open a XAML page like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="Login.Views.TiketStranica">
    
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ScrollView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <StackLayout>
            <Label x:Name="Lbl_Category" Text="Kategorija"/>
            <Picker x:Name="Entry_Category" Title="Izaberite kategoriju" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsCategory}" SelectedIndexChanged="Entry_Category_SelectedIndexChanged"/>

            <Label x:Name="Lbl_Subcategory" Text="Potkategorija"/>
            <Picker x:Name="Entry_Subcategory" Title="Izaberite potkategoriju" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSubCategory}" IsEnabled="False"/>

            <Label x:Name="Lbl_Description" Text="Opis"/>
            <Editor x:Name="Entry_Description" Placeholder="Unesite opis"/>

            <Label x:Name="Lbl_Urgency" Text="Hitnost"/>
            <Picker x:Name="Entry_Urgency" Title="Izaberite hitnost" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"/>

            <Label x:Name="Lbl_Attach" Text="Dokumenti"/>
            <Editor x:Name="Entry_Attach" Placeholder="Dokumenti" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            
            <ActivityIndicator x:Name="ActivitySpinner"  Color="Red" IsRunning="False" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
            
            <Button x:Name="Btn_Attach" Text="Dodajte dokument" Clicked="Btn_Attach_Clicked"/>
            <Button x:Name="Btn_Create" Text="Kreirajte tiket" Clicked="Btn_Create_Clicked"/>
        </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

while there is an AppConnectSDKBinding.dll included as a reference I cannot generate the page.
There is no error when running a page. Whole code that exists on the page (REST GET methods that collect some other data for display) works and is run in the background

Comment: Can you please share us some relevant code? It's not clear to me about what you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with interaction with the SDK that we needed to implement.
From SDK developer we got a workaround (not using an SDK but Wrapper that they developed).
Using wrapper solved this issue.